# Non exhaustive pattern in [String] ->String?

Tags: haskell

so I'm creating an function like this:

```
 unlinhas::[String]->String
 uninhas [x] = ""
 unlinhas (x:xs) = x ++ "\n" ++(unlinhas( xs))
```

that given a list of strings like this `["arroz","atum"]` is supposed to give `"arroz\natum\n"` the problem is that this function that I created says non-exhaustive patterns.

Comment: What do you do with the empty list?

Comment: first i putted unlinhas [] = ""  , but the function woulnt even load so i tried when has 1 element

Comment: what kind of debugging is that? "*I don't know what is wrong, so I simply change a few lines with random stuff, and hope that all of a sudden, it will work*"?

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but this is essentially just `unlines` (unlines also trails a newline, so it's literally just `init . unlines`)

Answer (score 5):

Your first pattern `[x]` is a **list with one element**. So the Haskell compiler is wondering what to do with an empty list.

Furthermore in your first line you write `uninhas`, instead of `unlinhas`, as a result the Haskell compiler thinks that you write two different functions.

Based on your specifications however, you want to process the empty list, so you can fix it with:

```
unlinhas:: [String] -> String
unlinhas [] = ""
unlinhas (x:xs) = x ++ "\n" ++(unlinhas( xs))
```

You can further cleanup the code, and write it as:

```
unlinhas:: [String] -> String
unlinhas [] = ""
unlinhas (x:xs) = x ++ '\n' : unlinhas xs
```

Comment: thx it works  by the way what is the diference between "" and ''?

Comment: @JoaoParente: that's because you named the first clause differently. It is now fixed.

Comment: @JoaoParente what's the difference between `"a"` and `'a'`? Check it out in GHCI.

Comment: @JoaoParente right, so `""` is the empty string `[] :: [Char]`, while `''` would be the empty Char (which isn't a thing, it's just an error).

Comment: thx very much @AdamSmith and  , i have been functions after functions and my brain randomly freezes Kappa

Comment: and @WillemVanOnsem couldnt mention 1 person per comment